# Get TOP rows out of child table WITH inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to inner join with a child table based on ID and get the top Row of the child table,
I am not joining to take any data out of the child table, its just to validate that child table record exists for parent table.
If I dont include TOP row there is chances of getting multiple rows of parent in the result set.

-- Chances of multiple rows in resultset for same PARENTID is possible

> SELECT P.PARENTID FROM    PARENT P
>   INNER JOIN CHILD C    ON C.PARENTID =
>   P.PARENTID  and C.ISACTIVE = 1

I need something like

> SELECT P.PARENTID FROM PARENT P
>   INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CHILD ) AS C
>   ON C.PARENTID = P.PARENTID
>   AND C.ISACTIVE = 1

I not sure how to get it working
I am curious if somebody can help me out or provide me any url where I could find the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you think **WHERE EXISTS** will do the job ?

```
SELECT P.PARENTID FROM PARENT P 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM CHILD C 
WHERE C.PARENTID = P.PARENTID 
AND C.ISACTIVE = 1)
```

Comment: Yes...i dont know how i forgot EXIST clause, this one is most efficient... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM parent WHERE parentId not in ( select parentid from child where isactive = 1 )
```

By doing this, you'll get a list of all the records in 'parent' that have no associated records in 'child'.

In order to retrieve the parents that have records in child, just reverse the criteria:

```
select * from parent where parentId in ( select distinct parentId from  child where isactive = 1 )
```

I've specified distinct here, in order to be sure that each parentId is listed only once, so that the parent itself is returned only once in the resultset as well.

Comment: Actually what I am looking for is to get the Parent's whose active Child exists

Comment: then just reverse the criteria, instead of 'not in', you specify 'in'

select * from parent where parentid in ( select parentid from child )

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the most efficient way, but:

```
SELECT p.parentid FROM parent p
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM child c WHERE c.parentid = p.parentid AND c.isactive)
    >= 1
```